# SetLocale does not update locale

Tags: javascript, internationalization, locale, telegraf.js

I have such code but locale does not updated after choosing. For example I choose French but default locale are used. Could you help to resolve this problem ?

```
i18n.configure({
  directory: __dirname + '/locales',
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  register: bot,
});

const listenConditions = new Map();

function setLocale(ctx, locale) {
  i18n.setLocale(ctx, locale);
}

bot.start((ctx) => {
  setLocale(ctx, "en");
  ctx.reply(i18n.__("language_selection"), Markup.keyboard([
    [i18n.__("language_english"), i18n.__("language_russian")],
    [i18n.__("language_ukrainian"), i18n.__("language_french")]
  ]));
});

bot.hears(i18n.__("language_english"), (ctx) => {
  setLocale(ctx, "en");
  ctx.reply(i18n.__("language_selected", { language: "English" }));
  showServiceOptions(ctx);
});

bot.hears(i18n.__("language_russian"), (ctx) => {
  setLocale(ctx, "ru");
  ctx.reply(i18n.__("language_selected", { language: "Русский" }));
  showServiceOptions(ctx);
});

bot.hears(i18n.__("language_ukrainian"), (ctx) => {
  setLocale(ctx, "uk");
  ctx.reply(i18n.__("language_selected", { language: "Українська" }));
  showServiceOptions(ctx);
});

bot.hears(i18n.__("language_french"), (ctx) => {
  setLocale(ctx, "fr");
  ctx.reply(i18n.__("language_selected", { language: "Français" }));
  showServiceOptions(ctx);
});
```

[locale json screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhyGv.png)

I tried to debug but I don't understand what's wrong